# Twilio on scriptcase

Tags: php, twilio-php

I am trying to setup Twilio on Scriptcase, I've already installed this Library, but I get a Parse error:

`syntax error, unexpected 'use' T_USE`.

This is my script:

```
sc_include_library("sys", "Twilio_II","twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php", true, true);  
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    if(!isset($fromphone))
    {
        $fromphone = '+1404xxxxxxxx';
    }
            $AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            $AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxx";
            $client = new client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage ($fromphone, $smsphone, $smsmessage, $surl);
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Also, is this code inside of a function? Or otherwise not in the global scope?

Comment: Hi I am using PHP 5.6.8 and no is not inside of a function